# Inversing Rows, ignoring empty cells

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Sheets and I am trying to inverse an array while ignoring the blank cells.
However, I managed to inverse it but I can't get GS to ignore the blank cells.

Thanks for your help!

Link to the sample input: [Inversing an array, ignoring blank cells](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SLu41pRCVX8ksnIA-hJtyTVEEJxSSn3NrJSuzf8WooA/edit#gid=0)

What I tried:

```
=INDEX($B$12:$B$19,rows(B12:$B$19))
```

Comment: Please post sample input and desired output as text table.

Comment: I just added a link to the sample input! Thanks for helping

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to sort the data _in place_, or created a sorted list _at another location_?

Comment: Sorry... just to be clear#2, if the index number in the column adjacent to the sorted colrs required as part of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=IFERROR(HSTACK(A12:A19,TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(SORT(A12:B19,1,0),2),1)),"")
```

If you only want colors name then could try-

```
=TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(SORT(A12:B19,1,0),2),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh! thank you so much! I am figuring how to use the TOCOL and CHOOSECOLS so I can use it with my work. Thank you, Harun24hr!

Comment: @L4ras Glad to know it helps.